# How to translate a WordPress plugin in any language?

Tags: wordpress, language-translation

I have completed my plugin, now want to provide a multilingual features for my users. I goggled about it, but it's hard to implement.

I've seen [WordPress translation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) but need basic steps to follow and translate my plugin.

**I have done these**

1. downloaded POEdit.
2. created 'french.po' file in plugin dir
3. complied 'french.po' -> 'french.mo'

**Need to do**

1. How to define **msgid** & **msgstr** in po file?
2. How to load po/mo file in plugin?
3. How to replace labels/text through po/mo file?
4. how to use **`__e()`** & **`___()`** to replace 'msgstr' in plugin pages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a plugin called, [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/), you don't need to use POEdit.

I'll show you an example of using 'localizationsample' as the text domain. In this case, the language files are in the /lang/ directory. They don't need to be those names in your actual plugin; they are just examples.

**Steps**

1. Add these lines in the plugin comment header to be recognized by Codestyling Localization.

   Text Domain: localizationsample
   Domain Path: /lang
2. Create a directory named `lang` in your plugin directory.
3. Install and activate the [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/) plugin.
4. Go to `Tools` -> `Localization`
5. Find your plugin and click on `Add New Language`
6. Select the language (country) to localize in the radio button and press `Create po-file` At this point make sure a .po file is created in the lang folder.
7. Press `Rescan` -> `scan now` This is recommended since in my system without doing this, the plugin always shows an error saying "not all items are using the same text domain."
8. Press `Edit` This will bring you another page listing the messages available to be translated. Those messages are the ones passed to the functions `__()` and `_e()` in the plugin code.
9. Click on `Edit` in the table next to `Copy` then you'll get a dialog box to type your translation for each message. Finish translating.
10. Press `generate mo-file` At this point, you should see a .mo file being created in the `lang` folder.
11. Change your locale specified in `wp-config.php` to reflect the translation. The default is `define('WPLANG', '');`

**Sample plugin**

```
/*  
    Plugin Name: Sample Localization
    Description: Demonstrates how to localize your plugin.
    Text Domain: localizationsample
    Domain Path: /lang
*/

// Localization
add_action('init', 'localizationsample_init');
function localizationsample_init() {
    $path = dirname(plugin_basename( __FILE__ )) . '/lang/';
    $loaded = load_plugin_textdomain( 'localizationsample', false, $path);
    if ($_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) && !$loaded) {          
        echo '<div class="error">Sample Localization: ' . __('Could not load the localization file: ' . $path, 'localizationsample') . '</div>';
        return;
    } 
} 

// Add Admin Menu 
add_action('admin_menu','localizationsample_menu');
function localizationsample_menu() { 
    add_options_page(
        'Localization Demo',            // admin page title
        'Localization Demo',            // menu item name
        'manage_options',               // access privilege
        basename(__FILE__),                         // page slug for the option page
        'localization_demo_adminpanel'  // call-back function name
    );
}
function localization_demo_adminpanel() {

    echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>';
    echo '<h2>' . __('Hi there!', 'localizationsample') . '</h2>'; 
    echo '<p>';
    _e('Hello world!', 'localizationsample');
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>'; // end of wrap
}
```

Comment: WebTechGlobal is now using this method and it works great. We are big fans of using Wordpress for development itself. This is a great example of why we should search for a plugin before an app if working with Wordpress.

Comment: As far as I can see, the  Codestyling Localization plugin is dead now.

Comment: 404 - **Whoops!** We couldn't find that plugin.

Comment: Regarding plugin link - This plugin has been closed and is no longer available for download.

Answer (score 5):

(THIS EXAMPLE IS A TRANSLATION to DEUTCH. YOU CAN CHANGE the customs to YOUR DESIRED names.)

in every plugins head, there is an unique name. 
(for example:

```
/*
Plugin Name: my-pluginname
.......
*/
```

then, in that plugin's folder, create a folder "languages";

then, into your plugin .php file (somewhere in the top), insert the initialization code:

```
class load_language 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'load_my_transl'));
    }

     public function load_my_transl()
    {
        load_plugin_textdomain('my-pluginname', FALSE, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages/');
    }
}

$zzzz = new load_language;
```

then open any text editor, then insert like this code (NOTE, THAT we are only adding two sample messages, "hello" and "bye", so , you can ADD AS MANY messages AS YOU WANT with the similar lines).

```
# English translations for PACKAGE package.
# Copyright (C) 2012 THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# Automatically generated, 2012.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: my-pluginname 1.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-08-06 13:46-0400\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2013-03-21 11:20+0400\n"
"Last-Translator: Automatically generated\n"
"Language-Team: none\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: iso-8859-1\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.4\n"


#: mypluginindex.php:87 (it is just a line of a note, to remind where our code appears)
msgid "mymessage1"
msgstr "Hello"

#: mypluginindex.php:88
msgid "mymessage2"
msgstr "Bye"
```

then save this file as "my-pluginname-en_US.po" (note, that .po is an extension of file, so check that your text editor program has not saved to "my-pluginname-en_US.po.TXT").

then  download POEDIT software, and open this  file. then edit the "translation" field, and then save as "my-pluginname-de_DE"
there will be generated two files ( If poEdit does not generate the second .mo file automatically, just go to File -> Preferences -> Editor and check the box that says "Automatically compile .mo file on save"),

then put those two file into "languages" folder.

after this, open wp-config.php and find this code:

```
define ('WPLANG, '');
```

and change to

```
define ('WPLANG, 'de_DE');
```

thats all.
when wordperss is loaded, it will read your plugins language file, with prefix -de_DE.

so, in the plugin's .php file, instead of:

```
echo "Something string";
```

you should use:

```
echo __("mymessage1", 'my-pluginname');
```

Finished. Now you should test your plugin.
p.s.used links:
    https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers
    http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress
    https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
    http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language