# WooCommerce Translate Terms & Conditions link?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am try'in to translate the terms & conditions link in WooCommerce but i can't find it. 
Any ideas on how i can translate the link ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following thread, which gives a detailed explanation of how to translate strings in a plugin or a theme,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642805/1993125