# Wordpress: what are __('Save Change') or _e('Save Change') commands?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning Wordpress and have noticed these expressions that I can meet very often:

_e('Save Changes')

__('Save Change')

What is this for? When to use _e, __?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147633/when-to-use-e-and-for-the-translation

Comment: Related: [How to translate a WordPress plugin in any language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12638547/1287812)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, [`_e`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/) is used to echo translated text where as [`__`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) retrieves the translation of the text.

It would be preferable to consult the documentation prior to asking a question.