# How do I edit contact fields?

Tags: php, css, customization, contact-form

I'm trying to edit the "Your name, Your email, Message & Send" fields on my contact form to a different language. I've already tried to change them in the "contact-form.php without much success. Am i looking in the wrong place/file? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the php file for the form...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THB_FRONTEND_JS_URL; ?>/jquery.validate.min.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo THB_FRONTEND_JS_URL; ?>/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.thb-contact-form').thb_validate();
    });
</script>

<form class="thb-contact-form" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <span id="thb-contact-form-name">
        <label for="contact_name"><?php _e('Your name', 'thb_text_domain'); ?></label>
        <input placeholder="<?php _e('Your name', 'thb_text_domain'); ?>" type="text" name="contact_name" value="" />
    </span>

    <span id="thb-contact-form-email">
        <label for="contact_email"><?php _e('Your email', 'thb_text_domain'); ?></label>
        <input placeholder="<?php _e('Your email', 'thb_text_domain'); ?>" type="text" name="contact_email" value="" />
    </span>

    <span id="thb-contact-form-message">
        <label for="contact_message"><?php _e('Message', 'thb_text_domain'); ?></label>
        <textarea placeholder="<?php _e('Message', 'thb_text_domain'); ?>" name="contact_message" rows="7" cols=""></textarea>
    </span>

    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Send', 'thb_text_domain'); ?>" id="submit">

</form>

<div id="thb-contact-form-result"></div>
```

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775135/what-the-heck-does-the-php-e-do

Comment: You're using wordpress's function `_e()` and as such your strings depend on the language set in the wordpress config and the MO files. See http://make.wordpress.org/docs/theme-developer-handbook/theme-functionality/internationalization/ and http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/29/internationalizing-localizing-wordpress-theme/

Comment: Thanks! I used the Codestyling plugin to create a mo. & po. file for me and then changed the language to my language in wp-config.php.